# How to implement Data push(server push) in worklist application

Tags: comet, bpel, fusion

I am planning to implement Server Push functionality in human workflow. Say when a task is assigned to a group and any of the group member updated the task, it has to update the task status automatically(without browser refresh) in other group members who are opened the worklist page.
How do I can achieve this? any ideas or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I can't see any connection to the BPEL tag. Talking about Oracle SOA?

Comment: Yep Vanto.. I am using Fusion 11g. I need to implement this and integrate into BPEL component via Java Embedding activity. Hope I am clear about your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a Realtime Web Server there are a bunch of options for different technologies listed on this [Realtime Web Technology Guide](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide).

If you can provide a bit more information about your choice of server technology I can be more specific about a recommendation/technology match.

Comment: I am using Oracle SOA Suite 11G.

Comment: Does Oracle SOA Suite 11G come with a Comet/WebSocket server? If not I'd some something like: Oracle DB CRUD trigger -> Push on to message queue -> consume from message queue (either from realtime web server or custom component) -> Distribute to connected clients.

Comment: Yep... Gotcha!! leggetter... Thank you.. Its working great. Instead of Oracle DB Trigger, according to my requirement I used WICKET ajax component.